# Reading SQL Query Results into Pandas without SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to read SQL queries into Pandas.  I don't want to use SQLAlchemy[1]. It is a connection to MySQL and I'm using mysql.connector.  I also do some direct queries without the need for pandas.  Pandas is depreciating direct db connections in read_sql but I can do it (with a depreciation warning).  I respect the fact that I can't count on it being there in the future.  I am requesting input on alternative strategies.  Since SQLAlchemy is off the table, I see the following options:

1. Write my own wrapper that does mysql.connector queries, retrieves the results, custom builds a pandas dataframe based on the cursor.description, and fill the data.  It will definitely work, but I think the corner cases (like converting timestamps to datetime) is tedious.  It is also recreating code that once existed efficiently
2. Use the warnings package and just suppress the warnings - recognizing the future challenges
3. Use a different dataframe package and different SQL interfacing
   library that is efficient and doesn't push the ORM model.  To be
   transparent, I haven't looked into this at all.

I tried SQLAlchemy.  It did not perform well.  This is because I am requesting a lot of data and it doesn't work well with a lot of data.  Also, it was a pain to pull out the raw connection and directly execute the query.  I am also concerned about how this would work from a connection pool perspective.

I have used mysql.connector for direct connections, but I have been lazy with column datatypes (i.e. no casting to datetime).  It works very well, but I wasn't going to go down the road with recreating the read_sql functionality from scratch.

[1] I know lots of folks are fans of ORM and SQLAlchemy.  I am not.  It is bulky and performs poorly on large datasets.  Additionally, when I also have direct queries that don't require pandas, it is a pain to do it in SQLAlchemy because it pushes ORM.  My goal is not to debate ORM/SQLAlchemy.

Comment: "it is a pain to do it in SQLAlchemy because it pushes ORM" - No, it doesn't. Right from the [overview](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/intro.html) the documentation clearly states that ORM is only part of the SQLAlchemy toolkit. You can choose not to use SQLAlchemy *at all* if you want, but if it "did not perform well" then the chances are good that you are just not using it to your advantage.

Comment: @GordThompson, I appreciate your input. I'll try to clarify.  It is true that SQLAlchemy acknowledges both the Core and ORM as two separate things.  The core is mostly ORM-like.  If you go through the SQLAlchemy Unified Tutorial and look at the Core, it barely mentions raw SQL. It push abstractions like "Table" and using a Select() function or Where() function.  By the of the tutorial, you are basically doing generic ORM and generating queries without SQL.  Even calling pandas.read_sql now requires that you wrap your raw query in text().

Comment: (sorry, more to add due to comment limits) ... also, until the recent version, you couldn't do a fetchone() on the raw execute,  It was only valid for the abstracted, ORM-style queries.  That was a performance problem.  As I originally asked, I was really just looking for the lightest (and high-performant) package for running raw SQL queries directly in a pandas table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best alternative you can use is [`connectorx`](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x) written in rust (fast and memory efficient).

I use it to replace `sqlalchemy` to extract several million records with each query. `connectorx` returns a dataframe with the correct column type.

Comment: I'll look into this, and respond back with my thoughts and then accept.  My first review of this suggests that it doesn't support connection pools, but I haven't had a chance to go into it deeply.